# How do different Form objects communicate in Flask-wtforms?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

A typical view is something like

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # do stufff
        return redirect(url_for('somewhere_else', param=param))
    return render_template('login.html', form=form)
```

What I'm confused about: when the `login()` view is called, isn't a new `LoginForm()` instantiated with `form = LoginForm()`? How does this brand new form ever `validate_on_submit()`?

Answer (score 3):

It's addressed in the first page of the [quick-start guide in the documentation](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#validating-forms):

> Note that you don’t have to pass request.form to Flask-WTF; it will load automatically. And the convenience validate_on_submit will check if it is a POST request and if it is valid.

So when you instantiate the form, it'll automatically load in the existing request if it can.

Answer (score 3):

Look at [the source code](https://github.com/lepture/flask-wtf/blob/master/flask_wtf/form.py) of `flask-wtf` (I removed unrelated fragments and added comments):

```
class Form(SecureForm):

    # ...

    def __init__(self, formdata=_Auto, obj=None, prefix='', csrf_context=None,
                 secret_key=None, csrf_enabled=None, *args, **kwargs):

        # ...

        if formdata is _Auto:
            if self.is_submitted():
                formdata = request.form  # !!! LOOK HERE !!!
                if request.files:
                    formdata = formdata.copy()
                    formdata.update(request.files)
                elif request.json:
                    formdata = werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict(request.json)
            else:
                formdata = None

        # ...
```

So, if you don't pass `formdata` explicitly to form's constructor and current request "is submitted" (the method is either PUT or POST), it uses the `request.form`.